# Implied protocol conformance of properties in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following

```
protocol FooPresentable {
   var bar: BarPresentable { get }
}

protocol BarPresentable {
}

class Foo {
  let bar: Bar 
}

extension Bar: BarPresentable {
}

extension Foo: FooPresentable {
}
```

And I get the error `Foo` does not conform to `FooPresentable`. Is it possible to have `Foo` conform to `FooPresentable` by just letting the compiler know that all `Bar`s conform to `BarPresentable`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have Foo conform to FooPresentable by just letting the compiler know that all Bars conform to BarPresentable

Not the way you're doing it, no. You've written a protocol that says: to conform to me, declare a variable `bar` that is *actually declared as BarPresentable*. Your Foo doesn't do that; it declares a variable `bar` that is declared as being Bar, which is not the same thing.

What you want is a generic protocol where the generic is *constrained to be an **adopter** of BarPresentable.*

Here is a complete example that compiles:

```
protocol FooPresentable {
    // this says: `bar` must be declared as a type that adopts BarPresentable
    associatedtype T: BarPresentable
    var bar: T { get }
}

protocol BarPresentable {
}

struct Bar {}

struct Foo {
    // behold, `bar` _is_ declared as a type that adopts BarPresentable
    let bar: Bar
}

extension Bar: BarPresentable {
}

extension Foo: FooPresentable {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
protocol FooPresentable {
   var bar: BarPresentable { get }
}
```

For `Foo` to conform to `FooPresentable`, the type of it’s `bar` property must be `BarPresentable`, which is not the same as having a `bar` property whose type conforms to `BarPresentable`. The type `BarPresentable` represents *any* type that conforms to `BarPresentable`:

```swift
struct Bar: BarPresentable {}
struct Baz: BarPresentable {}

let aBarPresentable: BarPresentable = Bar()
aBarPresentable = Baz()
```

What you probably want instead is an associated type:

```swift
protocol FooPresentable {
   associatedtype BarBarPresentable: BarPresentable
   var bar: BarBarPresentable { get }
}
```

This means that a type `A` conforming to `FooPresentable` must have a property `bar` which has a type (`TheBarPresentable`) specific to `A` that conforms to `BarPresentable`. I think this is best explained with an example:

```swift
class Foo {
    let bar: Bar
    init(bar: Bar) { self.bar = bar }
}

extension Foo: FooPresentable {
    typealias BarBarPresentable = Bar
}
```

In fact, you don’t need the explicit `typealias` declaration as Swift can infer this for you:

```swift
extension Foo: FooPresentable {}
```

Comment: Almost good, except the naming. Putting `The` on the front of stuff is an ancient anti-pattern. Either do `associatedtype BarPresentable: Module.BarPresentable` or what I did. I figure the latter is what's desired given that it has the same name as the property.

Comment: @Jessy I would normally have named it `Bar`, but I didn’t OP to confuse it with their own defined type `Bar` and I couldn’t come up with a better name. I’ll change it to `BarBarPresentable` though.

Answer (score 0):

`FooPresentable` has an associated type.

```swift
protocol FooPresentable {
  associatedtype Bar: BarPresentable
  var bar: Bar { get }
}

class Foo {
  let bar: Module.Bar = .init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use existential types or `associatedtype`

```
protocol FooPresentable {
    associatedtype B : BarPresentable
    var bar: B { get }
}
```

Or

```
protocol FooPresentable {
    var bar: any BarPresentable { get }
}
```

Which is correct depends on your actual use case.

[Check out Design protocol interfaces in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/110353)